# SO blog poor form layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, blog

I just read [Rolling out the Welcome Wagon: June Update](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/06/21/rolling-out-the-welcome-wagon-june-update/) and at the end there is this messy layout:

[image: Screenshot of the 'Leave a Reply' section. Input field names are in a narrow left hand column and the input fields are in a wide column on the right, except the last one which has the checkbox in the left column with the text. The last field is labeled 'Save my name, email, and website in this browser for the next time I comment.' and takes up 6 lines due to a lack of horizontal space. This text and checkbox is circled.]

I have used a red circle to indicate the part which I feel could have an improved appearance. It looked the same in IE11, Edge, and Firefox.

Perhaps the checkbox could be in the left column and its associated label in the right column.

Also, the comment field is not indicated as being a required field. And why is the "Website" field there?

(Layout rev 2018.6.22.30842)

Comment: Ohhh I have never noticed that SO blog allow comments.............

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson usually they're disabled, and a meta post is linked for discussion.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, but I did think I noticed that the blog comments looked a bit different than they used to. I was thinking you could vote on comments there before, but maybe I'm not remembering correctly.

Comment: @SadTestCoverageUnicorn Actually lately what's usual is that they're disabled and there *isn't* a meta post linked for discussion...

Comment: Is that a <TD> ?? :O

Comment: Also, that checkbox field looks even *worse* if you view the blog post on a mobile device. It becomes almost one word per line.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I thought it was pretty self-explanatory, but you can read this: https://www.lifewire.com/dont-use-tables-for-layout-3468941

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey Oh, sorry, I thought you meant there was a td somewhere in the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. The checkbox has been removed from the form.